# How to ignore the first and last element on each line when reading from a text file in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I need to read the contents of a fixed-format text file into a list of lists (LL) in Prolog but I want to exclude the first and last element on each line from the list for that line.  The very first line of the input file includes the number of rows (number of lists in LL) and columns (number of elements per list in LL).
An example input file with 3 rows and 4 columns is

```
3 4
A B C D Cd
1 9 3   7   4   7
2 6 8   4   0   32
3 2 4   3   8   42
Ab 140  21  331 41 55
```

and I would like

```
LL = [[9,3,7,4],[6,8,4,0],[2,4,3,8]]
```

How can I exclude the first and last element on each line from LL?

I have tried reading the SWI-Prolog documentation and searching for relevant threads here, but I have been unsuccessful.

```
readAll( InStream, [W|L] ) :-
     readWordNumber( InStream, W ), !,
     readAll( InStream, L ).

readAll( InStream, [] ) :-
     \+readWordNumber(InStream,_).

lst_2_lst_of_lst([], _N, []).
lst_2_lst_of_lst(L, N, LL) :-
    lst_2_lst_of_lst_helper(L, 1, N, LL).
lst_2_lst_of_lst_helper([H|T], N, N, [[H]|LL]):-
    lst_2_lst_of_lst(T, N, LL). 
lst_2_lst_of_lst_helper([H|T], N1 , N, [[H|TMP]|LL]):-
    N2 is N1 + 1,
    lst_2_lst_of_lst_helper(T, N2 , N, [TMP| LL]).
```

After calls to

```
...readAll(F,Input), ...
lst_2_lst_of_lst(Input, C, LL)
```

(C is 4, read in from first line of F, the text file)

My current result looks like this

```
LL = [[1,9  3   7  4 7,2,6   8   4 0 32],[3,2  4  3 8  42,Ab,140  21 331     41]]
```

and I would like it to look like this

```
LL = [[9,3,7,4],[6,8,4,0],[2,4,3,8]]
```

Comment: DCG is your friend. Perhaps an introduction is necessary.  - [Primer](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would separate the issue of parsing the file and cleanup lines.
Let's say we have a predicate that actually captures lines of tokens.
Then the following could be applied:

```
cleanup([_,_|Data],Clean) :-
    remove_last(Data,DataC),
    maplist([[_|L],C]>>remove_last(L,C),DataC,Clean).
remove_last(L,C) :-
    append(C,[_],L).
```

Capturing lines of tokens could be

```
readAll(InStream,[Line|Lines]) :-
    read_a_line(InStream,Line),
    readAll(InStream,Lines).
readAll(_InStream,[]).

read_a_line(F,L) :-
    read_line_to_string(F,S),
    S\=end_of_file,
    tokenize_atom(S,L).
```

To illustrate some of the IO facilities of SWI-Prolog, a quick test:

```
?- data(F),open_any(string(F),read,Stream,Close,[]),readAll(Stream,AllLines),cleanup(AllLines,Clean),Close.
F = "3 4\nA B C D Cd\n1 9 3   7   4   7\n2 6 8   4   0   32\n3 2 4   3   8   42\nAb 140  21  331 41 55",
Stream = <stream>(0x7f37b039e5d0),
Close = close(<stream>(0x7f37b039e5d0)),
AllLines = [[3, 4], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'Cd'], [1, 9, 3, 7, 4, 7], [2, 6, 8, 4, 0|...], [3, 2, 4, 3|...], ['Ab', 140, 21|...]],
Clean = [[9, 3, 7, 4], [6, 8, 4, 0], [2, 4, 3, 8]]
```

where `data(F)` actually binds `F` to the string you have in your example file.

Without lambda, we need an 'use once' predicate: for instance

```
cleanup([_,_|Data],Clean) :-
    remove_last(Data,DataC),
    maplist(remove_first_and_last,DataC,Clean).
    %maplist([[_|L],C]>>remove_last(L,C),DataC,Clean).
remove_first_and_last([_|L],C) :-
    append(C,[_],L).
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you.  I appreciate that it did not require adding a library, as I have not learned how to do that yet.

Comment: If possible, could you explain briefly what the >> operator does?  I've found a reference in the SWI-Prolog documentation to (>>)/2 "Calls a copy of lambda" but I generally find this documentation very hard to understand, and this case is no exception.

Comment: Yes, the documentation is a bit terse. So, I'll add the equivalent code without lambda (library(yall) implements lambda expressions s efficiently, it's a fairly recent addition to SWI-Prolog)

Answer (score 1):

Not absolutely certain that I understand your requirements. Your input looks a bit like tabular data, but it also looks a bit like a file format of some kind. Which one is it? How is it actually defined? What is the importance of the second row/line of your example input? Is "white space" the column separator? The questions can go on.

Here is how I will interpret your problem:

- The first line of input has two integer values separated by whitespace; those are "row" and "column" count `nrow` and `ncol`.
- The second row is not relevant (?).
- Then, a number of rows with whitespace-separated columns with integers in them follow. For `nrow` lines, make a list `nrow` long:

  - skip the first column;
  - take the next `ncol` columns and put them in a list of integers.
- skip the rest of input.

Writing this down is about 99% of the hard work (not saying it is hard, but for this problem, all of the "hardness" is in here).

Now you can go ahead and do the easy part: write the code. SWI-Prolog provides this great little library called `dcg/basics`. With it, I came up with this (in a hurry):

```
$ cat ignore.pl
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

read_stuff_from_stream(Stuff, Stream) :-
    phrase_from_stream(stuff(Stuff), Stream).

stuff(LL) -->
    integer(Nrow), white, whites, integer(Ncol), blanks_to_nl, !,
    string_without("\n", _Skip_this_line), "\n",
    rows(Nrow, Ncol, LL),
    remainder(_Skip_the_rest).

rows(0, _, []) --> !.
rows(Nrow, Ncol, [R|Rows]) --> { succ(Nrow0, Nrow) },
    skip_column,
    cols(Ncol, R),
    string_without("\n", _Skip_rest_of_line), "\n", !,
    rows(Nrow0, Ncol, Rows).

skip_column --> nonblanks(_Skip_this_column), white, whites.

cols(0, []) --> !.
cols(Ncol, [C|Cols]) --> { succ(Ncol0, Ncol) },
    integer(C), white, whites, !,
    cols(Ncol0, Cols).
```

It isn't "clean" code but it is a starting point. It works for the example you gave it.

```
3 4
A B C D Cd
1 9 3   7   4   7
2 6 8   4   0   32
3 2 4   3   8   42
Ab 140  21  331 41 55
$ swipl -q
?- [ignore].
true.

?- setup_call_cleanup(open('example.txt', read, In), read_stuff_from_stream(Stuff, In), close(In)).
In = <stream>(0x55f44e03de50),
Stuff = [[9, 3, 7, 4], [6, 8, 4, 0], [2, 4, 3, 8]].
```

There is room for improvement in like 10 different directions. If you don't understand something, ask.

Comment: Your summary of the input file process is correct.  Thank you for the comment on first writing down and clarifying the problem before starting to code; this method will definitely be helpful when approaching future coding problems.

Comment: @quiconque I knew how to do this long before I started programming. It is called "problem solving". If you are still learning it (and you are older than say 12 years old) you have missed the train.

Answer (score 1):

Complete code using DCG.

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics), except([eos/2])).       

:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).

parse(LL) -->
    size(Rows,Columns),
    header,
    rows(Rows,Columns,LL),
    footer.

size(Row,Columns) -->
    integer(Row),
    whites,
    integer(Columns),
    "\n".

header -->
    string_without("\n",_),
    "\n".

rows(Rows0,Columns,[Item|Items]) -->
    row(Columns,Item),
    { Rows is Rows0 - 1 },
    rows(Rows,Columns,Items).
rows(0,_Columns,[]) --> [].

row(Columns,Values) -->
    integer(_), % Ignore first value
    whites,
    values(Columns,Values),
    integer(_), % Ignore last value
    "\n".

values(Columns0,[Item|Items]) -->
    value(Item),
    { Columns is Columns0 - 1 },
    values(Columns,Items).
values(0,[]) --> [].

value(Item) -->
    integer(Item),
    whites.

footer -->
    rest_of_line, !.

rest_of_line -->
    [_],
    rest_of_line.
rest_of_line --> [].

readAll(LL) :-
    phrase_from_file(parse(LL),'C:/ll.dat').
```

---

Test cases

```
:- begin_tests(data).

test(1) :-
    Input = "\c
        3 4\n\c
        A B C D Cd\n\c
        1 9 3   7   4   7\n\c
        2 6 8   4   0   32\n\c
        3 2 4   3   8   42\n\c
        Ab 140  21  331 41 55\n\c
    ",
    string_codes(Input,Codes),
    DCG = parse(LL),
    phrase(DCG,Codes,Rest),
    assertion( LL == [[9,3,7,4],[6,8,4,0],[2,4,3,8]] ),
    assertion( Rest == [] ).

test(2) :-
    Input_path = 'C:/ll.dat',
    DCG = parse(LL),
    phrase_from_file(DCG,Input_path),
    assertion( LL == [[9,3,7,4],[6,8,4,0],[2,4,3,8]] ).

:- end_tests(data).
```

---

Example run of test cases

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: data .. done
% All 2 tests passed
true.
```

---

Example run

```
?- readAll(LL).
LL = [[9, 3, 7, 4], [6, 8, 4, 0], [2, 4, 3, 8]].
```

---

When ever you process list you should consider using DCG ([Primer](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg)).

The data is processed as character codes so the values for unification also have to be characters codes. People don't easily read character codes so Prolog has an option to turn double-quoted items into list of character codes. In the code `"abc"` is translated during compilation/consulting into `[97,98,99]`. This is done with a Prolog [flag](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=flags).

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).
```

Since using DCG is so common there is a library of predefined common predicates in [dcg/basics](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/dcg/basics.pl) in a [module](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=modules).

SWI Prolog has [unit test](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/plunit.html%27)).

To make it easier to format the input data for reading with unit test [\c](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=charescapes) is used.

The predicate that drives [DCGs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=DCG) is phrase but it comes it two very common variations.

1. [phrase/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=phrase/2) is typically used when the data is not read from a file. I also find it useful when developing and testing DCGs because you can see the entire stream of values. When the data is processed as a list of character codes and the input is a string, you will typically find [string_codes/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=string_codes/2) used with phrase/2. This is demonstrated in `test(1)`
2. [phrase_from_file/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=phrase_from_file/2) is typically used when you have the DCG working and want to read the data directly from a file.

---

View unit test in SWI-Prolog debugger.

If you want to use the debugger with a test case using SWI-Prolog then you 
start the debugger with

```
?- gtrace.
true.
```

Then run a specific test

```
[trace]  ?- run_tests(data:1).
```

Comment: Using `succ(N0, N)` instead of `N0 is N - 1` for counting down has the nice property that it fails when it reaches 0. Try `succ(X, 1)`, `succ(X, 0)`, `succ(X, -1)` to see what I mean.

Comment: I do not understand your approach to testing. You can do most of what you normally do in the body using the head of the tests. The `assertion`s especially keep me wondering what it is that makes them at all necessary.

Comment: It is great you are writing tests. The question is, why are you writing them this way? In the documentation to PlUnit you have many examples and they don't look much like what you are doing. So I naturally assume you are doing something special, but I am not clever enough to understand what is this special thing you are doing?

Comment: A question (that you can answer yourself if you feel like it) would be probably better. I try to learn from other people's code, it would be great if there is something new I didn't consider before.

Comment: Not sure if you read my question, or if it was too badly written. Example of strange stuff that has no apparent reason to my limited mind. `phrase(X, Y)` and `phrase(X, Y, Z), Z== []` seem to me to be the exactly same thing; but your code disagrees. Why?

Comment: Please disregard all my comments and stop adding to this answer. It is already too much, no one will ever bother reading this.