# Why do some DCG test cases use assertion( Rest == [])?

Tags: prolog, dcg

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55334468/1243762) uses `assertion( Rest == [] )?`

[pharse/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=phrase/3) is

```
phrase(:DCGBody, ?List, ?Rest)
```

Since [phrase/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=phrase/2) is equivalent to `phrase(DCGBody, InputList, []).` which is just `Rest = []` and in the test case `Rest == []`, whats the point? What benefit does adding `assertion( Rest == [] )` give?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`phrase(GB__2, Xs, [])` is equivalent to `phrase(GB__2, Xs)` but it is not necessarily the case that the first solution of `phrase(GB__2, Xs0,Xs)` will be `Xs == []`.

Here is a minimal example:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

ao1 --> "a" | [].

ao2 --> [] | "a".
```

While `phrase(aoX, "a")` just succeeds for both, `phrase(aoX, "a", Xs)` shows a difference in the sequence of solutions found.

```
?- phrase(ao1, "a", Xs).
   Xs = "a"
;  Xs = [].
?- phrase(ao2, "a", Xs).
   Xs = []
;  Xs = "a".
```